# R: lack of value in second column of first row causing read.table to recognise a 2D file as 1D

Tags: r, missing-data, read.table

I have a series of data frames in my R environment the I have read in as follows:

```
x <- list.files(pattern="nuc_occupancy_region"); 

for(i in seq_along(x)){
  print(x[i])
  assign(paste(x[i]), read.table(x[i], sep='\t', header=T, fill=T))
}

ESC=ls()[grep(ls(), pattern='ESC_nuc')]
MEF=ls()[grep(ls(), pattern='MEF_nuc')]
```

The list of files MEF often have missing data:
 eg.

## from command line

```
head MEF_nuc_occupancy_regionCybb9049012-9053217chrX.txt
9049012 26
9049013 
9049014 29
9049015 
9049016 26
etc.
```

The above file is not a problem as the missing values will be read as NA's and I can deal with that later.

However, in others the second value of the first row is missing....

```
117755994   
117755995   
117755996   
117755997   6
117755998   6
117755999   6
```

so despite the fact that each file has 2 columns, the lack of a second value in the first row of some of them causes them to be recognised as a file with a single column:

```
read.table(example.txt, sep='\t', header=T, fill=T)

117755994   
117755995   
117755996
117755997
6
117755998
6
117755999
6
```

Is there some way to avoid this as I need all the data frames to be in 2D?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a need for 'drop=FALSE'

Comment: Maybe try it without specifying `sep = '\t'`? When I run `read.table` over the text in your second code block with `header = FALSE, fill = TRUE` and nothing about a separator, I get the result you want.

Comment: If the files are all the same with same length columnd then look at `read_fwf` in package `readr` (or tidyverse)

Answer (score 0):

I had to just sort it out with python as 'readlines()' is unbiased to column number:

```
import os
list=os.listdir('.')
counter=0
files=[]
for i in list:
    file=open(i, 'r')
    print file
    lines=file.readlines()
    file.close()
    corrected=open(i+'formatted', 'a')
    print lines[0:9]
    for line in lines:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        line=line.split()
        if len(line)<2:
            line.append(0)
            corrected.write("{}\t{}\n".format(line[0], line[1]))
        else:
            corrected.write("{}\t{}\n".format(line[0], line[1]))
    corrected.close()
```